# How can I keep a computed column of a JSON version of all the data in the row?

Tags: json, sql-server, calculated-columns, sql-server-2017

We have a requirement to return JSONs based on numerous nested tables. I thought this would be quicker if the node tables had the JSON already prepared in a computed column.
Is it possible to use JSON_QUERY in a computed column or write a function to return all columns in the row as JSON? It gets rejected when I try to put it into a new computed column on the table designer. I can imagine a function that has to look up its own data instead of taking values directly from the columns, but that seems inefficient.
I welcome advice or alternative methods.

Comment: Presumably you tried this and it didn't work, and hence why you're asking. What was your attempt? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I couldn't get JSON_QUERY to work in the computed column. Can't find documentation on whether you can do this or not. I'm sure I can get a function to pass the primary key and return the JSON but that would not make use of the columns I already have access to in the table.

Comment: *"I couldn't get JSON_QUERY to work in the computed column."* again, show us your attempt(s). Put them in the question using the [edit] feature. Explain why they didn't work. Did you get an error? Unexpected results? Undesired behaviour? Caused your instance to crash?

Comment: Hard to say if putting it in a computed column is better or worse. It will definitely massively slow down inserts, it may speed up selects but it may not

Comment: @Charlieface The tables are rarely inserted to but the rows are often used in JSON_QUERYs. I thought if the column already had the row's JSON I could just use that instead of creating during queries.

Comment: Please [edit] and show your attempt, please also add the table definitions *as text*

Comment: Please, add some sample code like: what your data looks like, what JSON should look like, and what you have tried with. We are not asking this to make life miserable for you, but we really want to help - but if you don't give us something to go on, then it is really no use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use JSON_QUERY in computed column definitions. Part of your question is asking about a computed column returning a JSON representation of other column values, though, which requires more work.

For example, if you try to create the following table definition:

```sql
create table dbo.Foo (
  FooID int,
  Bar nvarchar(50),
  Baz date,
  ComputedJSON as (select FooID, Bar, Baz for json path)
);
```

You'll receive the following error:

```
Msg 1046 Level 15 State 1 Line 5
Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.
```

To work around this you'll need to move the subquery to a user-defined function, such as:

```sql
create function dbo.FooJson(@FooID int)
returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin
  return cast((
    select FooID, Bar, Baz
    from dbo.Foo
    where FooID=@FooID
    for json path
  ) as nvarchar(max));
end
go
create table dbo.Foo (
  FooID int,
  Bar nvarchar(50),
  Baz date,
  ComputedJSON as dbo.FooJson(FooID)
);
go
```

Now when you execute the following:

```sql
insert dbo.Foo (FooID, Bar, Baz) values (1, N'Hello', '21-Jan-2021');
select * from dbo.Foo;
```

You'll see the results:

| FooID | Bar | Baz | ComputedJSON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello | 2021-01-21 | [{"FooID":1,"Bar":"Hello","Baz":"2021-01-21"}] |

Comment: Thank you. That's the confirmation I needed and I can use that function with only slight adaptation.

Comment: Surprised that the function reads the data without it being committed to the table and without specifying a READ UNCOMMITTED transaction!